# Library used to make scroll-able and draggable image slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I like the way the image slider in this page works and I've been looking for a way to do it. But the information seem to be limited out there.

Site: http://stevenmengin.com/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need fullPage.js jQuery Plugin for fullscreen scrolling. You can get it from the link below:

http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/